# How to display on select the first group value selected first ? (with 2 different select)

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON (on JS file today but imported to API later) :

```
const data =
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Foo",
        "year": "18",
        "group": "AAA"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Doty",
        "year": "16",
        "group": "CCC"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Dito",
        "year": "20",
        "group": "BBB"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Bart",
        "year": "15",
        "group": "AAA"
    }
]
export default data;
```

And I have 2 "select" and i grouped the options by alphabetical order:

```
import data from './data';

const SelectComponent = () => {
  const [group, setGroup] = useState({});
  const optionSet = new Set();

  return (
  <>
    <Select onChange={(e) => setGroup(e.target.value)}>
      {data
        .filter((item) => {
           if (!optionSet.has(item.group)) {
           optionSet.add(item.group);
           return true;
         }
            return false;
         })
        .sort((a, b) => a.group.localeCompare(b.group))
        .map(({ id, group }) => (
          <option key={id} value={group}>
            {group}
          </option>
        ))}
    </Select>
    <Select>
      {data
         .filter((item) => {
           if (!optionSet.has(item.name)) {
           optionSet.add(item.name);
           return true;
         }
            return false;
         })
        .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        .map(({ id, name }) => (
          <option key={id} value={name}>
            {name}
          </option>
        ))}
    </Select>
  </>
  );
}

export default SelectComponent;
```

I want displayed on the second "select", just the first group of option selected first.

Example: if I selected group AAA on the first "select", I want displayed on the second "select" the options : Foo and Bart.

I have to use a second filter with include "group" state ?

Comment: your code is almost working. If you want to use `group` as a persistent value after the first value is selected, then this `group` has to show up in the second `Select` area, especially on `filter`. Of course we don't normally put that much of implementation in the rendering layer.

Comment: yes, I may not be able to filter "data" including the "group" state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to write something to facilitate the discussion.

```
  const [firstChoices] = useState([1,2,3,4,5])
  const [secondChoices, setSecondChoices] = useState([6,7])

  const onSelect = e => {
    const v = e.target.value
    // based on the v
    setSecondChoices(filtered(v))
  }

  return (
    <> 
      <Select choices={firstChoices} onSelect={onSelect} />
      <Select choices={secondChoices} />
    </>
  }
```

The above are high level code, it's not using your `Select` spec either. But the idea is that you sort out the logic before hand and store it in `state` before sending to underlying rendering layer.